# After angular version upgrade from 8 to 13 then "close" icon in the popup not working

Tags: angular, angular8, angular2-template, angular13, ng-template

```
<ng-template #userInfo>
    <div id="auth-users-roleinfo-popup" class="authorization-user-info asg-custom-background-color">
      <div class="authorization-user-info-header asg-custom-label-color">
        <div class="authorization-user-info-header-label-container">
          <span class="authorization-user-info-header-label" [ngbTooltip]="selectedOptionInfo.name" tooltipClass="general-tooltip" container="body">{{selectedOptionInfo.name}}</span>
          <span id="auth-users-editrole-label" class="authorization-user-info-edit-role mx-3 my-1" (click)="editRole(selectedOptionInfo)">Edit Role</span>
        </div>
        <i id="auth-users-selroleabout-icon" class="fa fa-close info-close authorization-user-role-info-close-icon" (click)="onAboutClick(selectedOptionInfo, null)"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="authorization-user-info-header-underline"></div>
      <div class="m-3">
        <div class="authorization-user-info-modal-content" *ngIf="selectedOptionInfo.description != ''">
          <p class="authorization-user-info-sub-header asg-custom-label-color" i18n="@@AuthorizationUser_UserInfo_Description">Description</p>
          <p class="authorization-user-info-sub-header-desc asg-custom-label-color">{{selectedOptionInfo.description}}</p>
          <div class="authorization-user-info-subheader-underline"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="authorization-user-info-modal-content" *ngIf="applications.length">
          <p class="authorization-user-info-sub-header asg-custom-label-color" i18n="@@AuthorizationUser_UserInfo_Scope">Scope</p>
          <p class="authorization-user-info-sub-header-desc asg-custom-label-color">{{getSelectedApplication(selectedOptionInfo)}}</p>
          <div class="authorization-user-info-subheader-underline"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="authorization-user-info-modal-content">
          <p class="authorization-user-info-sub-header asg-custom-label-color" i18n="@@AuthorizationUser_UserInfo_Permissions">Permissions</p>
          <p class="authorization-user-info-sub-header-desc asg-custom-label-color">{{getSelectedPermissions(selectedOptionInfo)}}</p>
          <div class="authorization-user-info-subheader-underline"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="authorization-user-info-modal-content">
          <p class="authorization-user-info-sub-header asg-custom-label-color" i18n="@@AuthorizationUser_UserInfo_Assignments">Is Assigned to User/Group</p>
          <p class="authorization-user-info-sub-header-desc asg-custom-label-color">{{selectedOptionInfo?.assignments?.join(', ')}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
```

The "close" button in the Role info popup is not working. This issue might have occurred after the angular 13 upgrade.
Note : Clicking anywhere on the Role-info pop-up body except the "close" icon closes the popup. But clicking on the "close" icon doesn't close the popup.

```
id="auth-users-selroleabout-icon" 
class="fa fa-close info-close authorization-user-role-info-close-icon"
```

What should I add in the CSS file for working the close icon?

[image]

Comment: "Clicking anywhere on the Role-info pop-up body except the "close" icon closes the popup". Is this intended behaviour?

Comment: Nope, while clicking on close icon that popup should be closed

Comment: Then you need to provide more detail on the Pop-up. How does it work? Is the popup from a library you're using? It could also be relevant to show the call to the pop up component.

Comment: In html file  
 `</div>
        <i id="auth-users-selroleabout-icon" class="fa fa-close info-close authorization-user-role-info-close-icon" (click)="onAboutClick(selectedOptionInfo, null)"></i>
      </div>` 
In scss  file  
   `.authorization-user-role-info-close-icon{
  cursor: pointer;
}`   
In ts file    
`onAboutClick(option, event) {
    this.isRoleInfoIconClicked = true;
    if(event)
      this.clickEvent = event;
    this.selectedItemList.forEach(e => {
      if (e.name != option.name) {
        e.isInfoClicked = false
      }
    });`

Comment: this code works in angular 8 version but not working in angular 13 version

Comment: Please edit your question with the code, instead of posting a comment. Also the code you show doesn't seem to have any impact on closing the popup. How is the ng-template in your question used?